# Change the $(Process) number to 1 instead of 0 in HTCondor

Tags: variables, condor

I am wondering how I could change the variable $(Process) to start at 1 instead of 0 in HTCondor.

I am trying things like this

```
Number = ($(Process)+1)
```

To define a new variable that starts in 1 and not 0. But doesn't work. Could someone please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(Process) macro is fixed, and can't be changed, but you can do math on it, via some convoluted syntax.  To pass $(Process) + 1 as an argument to you job, try the following:

```
Arguments = $$([1 + $(PROCESS)])
```